# MVC 5 and bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I my solution didn’t working, can’t add bootstrap modal in link. search any help:)

```js
 $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
            $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
                    /*backdrop: 'static',*/
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

```cs
 @Html.ActionLink("Создать новую", "Create", new { }, new { @class = "btn btn-default viewDialog", data_dialog_title = "Создание модели" } )
```

Comment: unclear information. :(

Comment: What does the link you have shown got to do with the script? What are the elements `$("a[data-modal]")`, `$('#myModalContent')` and `$('#myModal')` that your script refers to.?

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Создать новую2", "Create", new { }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger", data_toggle = "modal", data_target = "#myModal" })

Answer (score 0):

> Bootstrap Modal -

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" style="resize:both">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="text-align: center"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add Friends</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="modalInner" class="modal-body" style="overflow-y:auto; height:450px">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> anchor tag

```
<a href="#" class=" btn btn-white btn-xs pull-right"                                       onclick="getData('@ViewBag.LoginUserId')">OPen MOdal
                                            </a>
```

> Script File

```
 function getData(data) {
        //alert(data);
        $.ajax('@Url.Action("ABC")/' + data).done(function (data) {
            $('#modalInner1').html(data);
            $('#myModal1').modal({});
        });
    }
```